# Debian: Kill a Screen session through the web

Tags: bash, shell, script, php, gnu-screen

I have php code that is as follows (kill.php):

```
<?php echo exec("/home/duke/aa/scripts/test.sh");  ?>
```

test.sh looks like this:

```
screen -S server -X quit
```

If I run the php code in the terminal `php screen -S server -X quit` the script kills the screen session.

However, if I point my web-browser to http://mywebsite/test.php, it displays "No screen session founds" and it doesn't kill the screen session. What can I do to make it work through the web-browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration is to run all PHP pages (and their spawned commands) as *`www-data`* user, which means they only have access to sessions owned by *`www-data`*.

You need to run the script under your own user account, which can be done by:

- using **`sudo`**; for example, the following *sudoers* entry:

  ```
  www-data: ALL=(duke) NOPASSWD: /home/duke/aa/scripts/test.sh
  ```

  will let you run `exec("sudo -u duke /home/duke/aa/scripts/test.sh");`
- or installing **suPHP**: the PHP script will then be run under its owner's account.

---

Your current example runs the script *twice*, which may have various side effects. Get rid of the second `exec()` call – or even better, use `system()` or `passthru()` instead – if you want to display the script's output.

Comment: The sessions are owned by root. Should I modify the sudoers entry aswell? So in my case do I do exec("sudo -u root /path/to/.sh")?

Comment: @Kevin: Correct. Although *`root`* is the default for *sudo*, so you can use just `sudo /path/to/.sh` in this case.

Comment: Would you please explain how I may modify my sudoers entry?

Comment: @Kevin: Replace `(duke)` with `(root)`, and fix the .sh path if needed.

Comment: I can place this `www-data: ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/duke/aa/scripts/test.sh` anywhere within the sudoers entry?

Comment: @Kevin: The recommended way to edit it is through `visudo`, which verifies that the syntax is correct; but the file itself is `/etc/sudoers`, along with other configuration files. Put the line at the end of the file. See `man 5 sudoers` for syntax documentation.

Comment: To save some trouble, I temporarily commented out this line `%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` which I assume allows any user to sudo without a password. Do I need to reboot a module now? Pointing my web-browser to the php file still doesn't work.

Comment: @Kevin: The line you commented only affects users belonging to the group *`sudo`* (as in `/etc/group`), not "any user". Changes to `/etc/sudoers` take effect immediately if the syntax is correct. Try `sudo -u www-data sudo /home/duke/aa/scripts/test.sh`, also see `/var/log/auth.log` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: ah, it says syntax error on line 22. I restored the sudoers file back to its original state but added `www-data: ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/duke/aa/scripts/test.sh` at the bottom. However, it appears that isn't syntaxically correct. Here is my sudoers file: http://pastebin.com/HMKw72Z8

Comment: @Kevin: You have an extra `:` after `www-data`. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the cause is that you start the screen session as another user than your web server user (possibly `www-data`), but since the script will run as your web server user when started via the browser, it doesn't have the right to send commands to another user's screen session.

How to fix this is dependent on how your originally start the screen session. If it is possible to start it as the web server user, this will be the simplest solution, but other options might include sudo or more complicated measures (*). Tell us more about what you are doing, so we can make useful suggestions.

(*) I've seen a "solution" for this kind of problem where the PHP script would write a special file, which was detected by a cronjob that started it's work only when the file was present...

Comment: SvenW, the screen sessions were started with the root account, so I have modified the php code to look like this `exec("sudo /home/duke/aa/scripts/test.sh");` However, no luck still. Any other suggestions before I try starting the sessions with www-data?

Comment: Did you put www-data in the sudoer's file?

Comment: yes this is what my sudoer's file looks like: http://pastebin.com/HMKw72Z8

Comment: @Kevin: `sudo` by itself doesn't change the user environment completely, e.g. try `sudo who am i` and you'll still get info on the original user and pty. However, you can tell `screen` which user to use, e.g. `screen -r sessionowner`.

Comment: @Tom: `who` checks the *utmp* file, but `screen` just uses the current UID, so the latter should work fine with `sudo`.